# Can Core Data be used from within a Swift Playground?

Tags: core-data, swift, xcode6, swift-playground

I'm just beginning with Swift and was wondering if Playgrounds has access to Core Data. If so, it would be very handy to pre-populate a DB before placing it on an iOS project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an iOS playground you can successfully `import CoreData` and then invoke functions defined in the CoreData interfaces.